# How to Highlight the particular area of view when Push Notification AlertView Appears on View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, notifications, uialertview

I am new to iOS Application development...

I have one View on which push logo Area .
Also i have one `PushNotificationAlertView` on my view.

Now my question is, can i able to do like following Highlight  push logo Area when my `PushNotificationAlertView`  appears.

**The alert is coming from the `UIUserNotificationSettings`**
In **AppDelegate.m**

```
UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

i am getting the alert like following image

[image]

But **I want like** following image please help me

[image]

How can i do this ?
please help me .:)

Comment: what you want? you just set background to your label Push Logo?

Comment: @rohitSidpara thanks i want the particular area view highlighted in alert view

Comment: you can achieve this using with custom uialertview or toast label.

Comment: alert is coming from UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

Comment: how can we customize the alert

Comment: it is not label .. background image for the view i want the area of push logo

Comment: you want to highlight the Push Logo area?

Comment: Make a custom view for Push Logo, then use notifier from `didRecieveRemoteNotification` to particular view i.e push logo view controller, then highlight the custom view of push logo.

Comment: @Santo can you provide the sample code ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Custom View or a Label to make it highlight.

Use this below code to Notify to your viewcontroller.

[Use Notifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704961/3747974)

Add your snippet in the below of function from the link

```
if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"TestNotification"]) {
//highlight the view or label by changing color or text or what you want
}
```